# what happens when an xml file tries to be read while it is being written?

Tags: php, ios, xml

I have an iOS app that allows users to update the cover charges at local bars. The data is then displayed on the app for other users to see. The updates are made by sending a request to a php script and then the script updates and xml file. What will happen if a user tries to read the xml while another user is updating it, i.e. while the file is being rewritten with a new update?

Thanks!

Comment: unless your xml file is huge and you have thousands of hits a second it shouldnt be a problem.
if you have that kind of traffic it would be more beneficial to use a database anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user has a 50-50 chance of getting the updated version, depending on the server speed and there connection speed it may differ. I agree with AMayer, once the file gets big it's going to be hard on your server to download and upload the **ENTIRE** xml file again and again! I would just setup a MySQL database now and use it instead of the XML.

Comment: For sure. He should for sure set up a MySQL database. He is probably reading it with simplexml or domdocument too. In which case would become very slow once the file becomes quite large